# There is a difference while debayer an image with cmd ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, batch

I have such a bayer image https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OjHQyR44ECMMs4BtlZacejkmgSjeY2Nq/view?usp=sharing

I need to get two output files

1. Directly debayer this image and save it as `.bmp`
2. Debayer the image compress it to `.h264` and the decompress and save as `.bmp`

In order to do this, I use such a batch script

```
@echo off

set main_dir=my_main_dir
set file_name=orig_bayer
set input=%main_dir%\%file_name%.bmp
set output_direct_debayer_bmp=%main_dir%\gpl_cmd_direct_decompress.bmp
set output_h264=%main_dir%\result_h264_%file_name%.h264
set output_h264_to_bmp=%main_dir%\gpl_cmd_decompress.bmp
set video_size=4096x3000

rem direct debayering 
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i %input% -vf format=gray -f rawvideo pipe: | ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format bayer_rggb8 -video_size %video_size% -i pipe: -pix_fmt yuv420p %output_direct_debayer_bmp%

rem debaer -> h264 -> decompress
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i %input% -vf format=gray -f rawvideo pipe: | ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -framerate 30 -f rawvideo -pixel_format bayer_rggb8 -video_size %video_size% -i pipe: -c:v hevc_nvenc -qp 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p %output_h264%
ffmpeg -y -i %output_h264% -f image2 %output_h264_to_bmp% -hide_banner

pause
```

So the problem that with #1 approach I

```
...
rem direct debayering 
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i %input% -vf format=gray -f rawvideo pipe: | ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format bayer_rggb8 -video_size %video_size% -i pipe: -pix_fmt yuv420p %output_direct_debayer_bmp%
...
```

I get such an output https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-DA2440zZ2F9WRcd15iqFUt3UhtkQRZT/view?usp=sharing

and with #2 approach

```
...
rem debaer -> h264 -> decompress
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i %input% -vf format=gray -f rawvideo pipe: | ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -framerate 30 -f rawvideo -pixel_format bayer_rggb8 -video_size %video_size% -i pipe: -c:v hevc_nvenc -qp 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p %output_h264%
ffmpeg -y -i %output_h264% -f image2 %output_h264_to_bmp% -hide_banner
...
```

I get such an output https://drive.google.com/file/d/103dtgaDVaXsNy13XHaVLSgugQhh0Uj9N/view?usp=sharing

The second one has a difference in the colors...

Comment: Once you convert an image using a lossy format, you can never get back the original colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like a bug in the color conversion algorithm, but I can't be sure.

When replacing `-pix_fmt yuv420p` with `-pix_fmt yuv444p` the colors are the same as the direct conversion.

- The color conversion path: **Bayer -> yuv420p** modifies the colors.
- The color conversion path: **Bayer -> yuv444p** works correctly.

The common [Demosaicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosaicing) algorithms converts from Bayer to RGB, and not from Bayer directly to YUV, but I don't know the internal conversion pipeline used by FFmpeg.

I found a solution that encodes yuv420p with the following color conversion path:
**Bayer -> yuv444p -> yuv420p**

The solution uses the `format` video filter.
Add the arguments: `-vf format=yuv444p` after `-i pipe:`.

Use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i %input% -vf format=gray -f rawvideo pipe: | ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -framerate 30 -f rawvideo -pixel_format bayer_rggb8 -video_size %video_size% -i pipe: -vf format=yuv444p -c:v hevc_nvenc -qp 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p %output_h264%
```

---

Results (reduced size) left to right:

- Without `-vf format=yuv444p` (incorrect colors):
- With `-vf format=yuv444p` (correct colors):
- Direct conversion (correct colors):

[image] [image] [image]

---

Note:

- [HEVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding) is H.265 and not H.264